# What is a good edit? and is this maybe a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, revision-history

for this question [Operation must be an updatable query - Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591144/operation-must-be-an-updatable-query-access/31591745)

I change this:

```
UPDATE [tblSchedule] Set [tblSchedule].ItemNo = (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM [tblStock] WHERE ((([tblStock].Bookcode)=[tblSchedule].[PartCode])));
```

For this:

```
UPDATE [tblSchedule] 
SET [tblSchedule].ItemNo = 
         (SELECT DISTINCT Item 
          FROM [tblStock], [tblSchedule] 
          WHERE [tblStock].Bookcode=[tblSchedule].[PartCode]
         );
```

Reformat the code so no need to scroll ard remove unnecesary () in the `WHERE`

And I got two Reject:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I understand format is the eye of the programmer. But I think my version is easier to read. More acurate because remove unnecesary (). And I'm certainly doesn't harm readability.

### Now the Bug part.

On the top of the page I still have this message

> Thanks for your edit!
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

But I already got +2 for edit answer

> +2 51 mins ago edit    Operation must be an updatable query - Access

And if you check revision
there say my review was accepted.

> edit approved 46 mins ago
>       Juan Carlos Oropeza

Also if you see marc_s review he is using my fix code. But now I can't see marc_s edit even when his was accepted after mine, becasue mine review is pending.

Comment: I see marc_s edit following yours. Yours is approved, and then his is in, all taking place an hour ago. Try clearing your cache. His entry in the revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31591144/5

Comment: Hmm I'm can't see what you are talking about.  According to the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31591144/revisions) marc_s has the most recent edit.  And [your suggestion was approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8906023) by him too (via an "improve edit" review).

Comment: I would recommend asking one question at a time

Comment: And I'm not sure if it's relevant, but you did submit two revisions to that post. One was rejected, the other was approve-edited by a reviewer with the powers to do so

Comment: @DeadChex I guess was cache issue. I open in firefox instead of chrome and looks ok

Answer (score 5):

Your edit was [further expanded upon](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8906023) by Marc. This means two things:

- Your edit is immediately accepted and you're awarded two reputation
- They now have a chance to edit the post further

Since you didn't remove the "Thanks" bit, that was likely the right decision on his part.

As to why you had a couple of rejections:  perhaps they were being lazy, knew that you hadn't 100% edited the question and decided to take a cop-out?